# PHP debugging in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: php, debugging, drupal, intellij-idea, xdebug

Ok, I'm probably stupid but I cannot make it to work.

The setup is:

- Ubuntu
- apache2
- xdebug
- IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.3 Ultimate
- IntelliJ IDEA PHP Plugin

xdebug is installed.

I would like to debug Drupal site, on my local machine, the project is here:

```
/var/www/luken/my-site
```

and URL is here:

```
http://localhost/luken/my-site
```

Because I couldn't create a project from existing sources, I created new project (web module) from scratch there. Now the thing is that if I'm running configuration for "PHP Script" - debugger works. But if I try to use configuration for PHP Web Application (so project would be opened in browser) it cannot connect to debugger. I tried a lot of things, and different mappings but obviously I'm missing something stupid. How configuration should look with above setup?

Comment: See http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/02/zero-configuration-debugging-with-xdebug-and-phpstorm-2-0/ . Verify that `xdebug.remote_enable=1` in `php.ini`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course. I found answer few minutes after posting a question, regardless of hour of investigation before, but here it is:

I read somewhere wrong information that you doesn't need to configure xdebug. In reality, you need to modify /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini . I added there:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Which I read about in article about configuring Netbeans, and the thing worked. And precisely:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
```

^ This line is only required.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using PHPs command line interface (cli), a different php.ini is being used. Thus, either edit the `/etc/php/version/cli/php.ini`, or specify a php.ini explicitly, like

```
php -S localhost:8080 -t "/var/www/html/my_project" -c "/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini"
```